# Which property in my css is causing the intended effect to work in Safari but not Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a personal website and am trying to get a particular scrolling effect, where the page is separated into sections and each section overlaps the next section. Meanwhile, the content of each section stays fixed so that the content for each section never moves, but rather is revealed by each section scrolling into place.

My issue is that with the code I have now, I have achieved this effect in Safari, but when I open the same file in Chrome, it doesn't work at all. I isolated the particular effect I am going for in the following code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /*    position: -moz-sticky;*/
  /*    position: -ms-sticky;*/
  /*    position: -o-sticky;*/
  top: 0;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

#first {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 1;
}

#second {
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 2;
}

#third {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="Vishal Cherian" description="Vishal's personal and professional website">
  <title>Vishal | Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section" id="first">
    <div class="fixed">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="second">
    <div class="fixed">
      <h1>Goodbye</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section" id="third">
    <div class="fixed">
      <h1>Hello Again</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you open this code in Safari, you will see the effect, but if you open it in Chrome, it is completely different.

I am assuming the problem lies in my CSS file, but from the research I have done, I cannot find any disparity in the way Chrome treats any of the individual CSS properties I used compared to how Safari treats them. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The issue is almost certainly related to the combination of `sticky`, wrapped around an element with `fixed`.  This is creating a complicated state, where your z-index isn't working as expected.  Note that it's not just Chrome either - Firefox doesn't handle it the way you want (haven't tested IE).  (As for difference between Chrome and Safari, there is absolutely a difference in the way [they handle sticky](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Comment: By the way, the effect is very cool when it works in Safari! I would have thought that would only be possible with javascript....

Comment: If I had to guess, it's probably different implementations of the stacking order regarding sticky since it's relatively new.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: So I tried writing it differently without the sticky positioning, and I am getting the same issue, I wrote it up in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xsony3zb/18/